# How to apply regex over all the rows of a dataset?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataset as follow:

```
    data = {"C1" : ['DDDSSDSSDS','SSDDDSSDDS', 
   'DDDDDDDDDD','SSSSSSSSSS','SSSSSSSDSS','DDDDDSDDDD','SDDDDDDDDD']}
    dt = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(dt)
```

For each string I want to get the positions of first element and last element of each "Uninterrupted S groups". For example, for first row I have 'DDD**SS**D**SS**D**S**' (as you see I have three groups of S)  and my favorite output for this "S group"s is something like `[(3,5),(6,8),(9-10)]` which shows the positions for first and second and third "uninterrupted S groups" in first row.

So an example of output could be as:

```
           C1                         C2
0  DDDSSDSSDS       [(3, 5), (6, 8), (9-10)]
1  SSDDDSSDDS  [(0, 2), (5, 7), (9, 10)]
2  DDDDDDDDDD                         []
3  SSSSSSSSSS                  [(1, 11)]
4  SSSSSSSDSS          [(0, 7), (8, 10)]
5  DDDDDSDDDD                   [(5, 6)]
6  SDDDDDDDDD                   [(0, 1)]
```

My current solution is:

```
def split_it(mystring):
    x = re.findall('(S*)', mystring)
    if x :
      return(x)

dt['C2'] = dt['C1'].apply(split_it)
print(dt)
```

which leads to the following output:

```
0  DDDSSDSSDS  [, , , SS, , SS, , S, ]
1  SSDDDSSDDS  [SS, , , , SS, , , S, ]
2  DDDDDDDDDD   [, , , , , , , , , , ]
3  SSSSSSSSSS           [SSSSSSSSSS, ]
4  SSSSSSSDSS        [SSSSSSS, , SS, ]
5  DDDDDSDDDD  [, , , , , S, , , , , ]
6  SDDDDDDDDD  [S, , , , , , , , , , ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Check out this article it may help to solve your problem https://towardsdatascience.com/apply-and-lambda-usage-in-pandas-b13a1ea037f7

Comment: @Marat So, what could be a better tool to answer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
def split_it(mystring):
    return [(m.start(), m.end()) for m in re.finditer('S+', mystring)]
```

Output:

```
>>> dt['C1'].apply(split_it)
0    [(3, 5), (6, 8), (9, 10)]
1    [(0, 2), (5, 7), (9, 10)]
2                           []
3                    [(0, 10)]
4            [(0, 7), (8, 10)]
5                     [(5, 6)]
6                     [(0, 1)]
Name: C1, dtype: object
```

The `re.finditer('S+', mystring)` returns all match objects found in the string and you may get the start and end positions via `.start()` and `.end()` calls.

Note you got empty matches in your output because `S*` matches *zero or more* `S` chars, you need to use `+` to match *one or more*.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply regex using findall:

```
(
    dt
    .assign(C2= lambda x: x['C1'].str.findall('S+'))
    .assign(C2= lambda x: x.apply(lambda s: [(s[0].find(item),s[0].find(item)+len(item)) for item in s[1]] ,axis=1))
)

           C1                        C2
0  DDDSSDSSDS  [(3, 5), (3, 5), (3, 4)]
1  SSDDDSSDDS  [(0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 1)]
2  DDDDDDDDDD                        []
3  SSSSSSSSSS                 [(0, 10)]
4  SSSSSSSDSS          [(0, 7), (0, 2)]
5  DDDDDSDDDD                  [(5, 6)]
6  SDDDDDDDDD                  [(0, 1)]
```